# Add an image acting as a link toward it's own location

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

Using `rmarkdown` and the `include_graphics` function from `knitr` I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<a href="image.png"><img src="image.png" alt="image" width="30%"></a>
```

Where I can see a small version of an image and click on it to see its full size original version. I am sure there is an easy way to wrap something like:

````
```{r ,out.width="30%"}
knitr::include_graphics('image.png')
```
````

within an html link but I can't find how.

What I like with `knitr::include_graphics()` is that

1. it's in a chunk so I can generate the image's names with `R`
2. it copies images to the final folder where I want my `Rmardown` code to be compiled.

An example of what I would like to do but I don't how nor if it's possible:

````
```{r ,out.width="30%"}
images=paste0('image',1:3,'.png')
for( i in images){
    #open <a href = i>
    knitr::include_graphics(i)
    #close </a>
}
```
````

Should do something like:

```
<a href="image1.png"><img src="image1.png" alt="image" width="30%"></a>
<a href="image2.png"><img src="image2.png" alt="image" width="30%"></a>
<a href="image3.png"><img src="image3.png" alt="image" width="30%"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the chunk option `fig.link`, e.g.,

````
```{r, out.width="30%", fig.link='image.png'}
knitr::include_graphics('image.png')
```

```{r}
images = paste0('image', 1:3, '.png')
```

```{r, out.width="30%", fig.link=images}
knitr::include_graphics(images)
```
````

Comment: That's what I love about knitr. So many useful features one could manually fiddle together are already implemented as a built-in option.

Comment: This is awesome thanks Yihui! and sorry for missing that in the doc. it sounded strange that nothing like this existed, but I thought that I looked carefully ; I was probably not using the good search terms (the idea is simple but there is lot of way to formulate it). hope this helps people who missed it as I did.

Comment: @SimonC. It's definitely not your problem but mine. I thought I documented this option at https://yihui.org/knitr/options/, but it turns out I didn't. I'll add it there. I'm glad that you asked the question to remind me of something I've almost forgotten. It's not rare that I implement a feature and forget to document it, and sometimes I'm just too lazy to work on the documentation because it can be equally time-consuming...

Comment: Indeed documenting is high time consuming when done right and you did an awesome job already with all your packages so no-one can blame you!
In addition to my initial question, I wonder now if there is a straightforward way to do that for normal plot, using the label of the chunk? I can do it by adding a chunk before, to generate the vector of filenames using the label + a number that increases for each `plot` call, but this means to know beforehand the number of call to plot and adds a chunk everywhere (it's less a problem with include_graphic, as I need to add this chunk anyway).

Comment: @SimonC.I think [this](https://gist.github.com/ClaudiusL/8b214e253810068ef5fda8963e62f554) should do the trick. Basically, use `eval.after` and the option `self_contained: false`. The latter is a not-so-nice workaround that ensures that the images are not base64 encoded but created as actual files. Not sure if this can be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply do:

````
<a href = "./image.png">
```{r, out.width="30%"}
knitr::include_graphics('./image.png')
```
</a>
````

For me, this works.

Comment: Oh yes that indeed works, thank you for the answer. But what I would like ideally is to be able to use R to generate the generate the image name (thus I can loop on some variable in my workspace), I will update my question to reflect that.

Comment: @SimonC.Jrm_FRL's answer (almost) gives you that. Just don't write the `a` tags verbatim, but print them via `cat`: `cat(sprintf('<a href = "%s">\n%s\n</a>', i, knitr::include_graphics(i)))`. Untested.

Answer (score 1):

adding on top of what Jrm_FRL said, just incase you ment the link takes you where the link is originally from I added this code, had to shorten the link with stackoverflow and imgur, let me know if you have issues.

````
  ---
  title: "picture_as_link"
  author: "stackoverfl"
  date: "5/27/2020"
  output: html_document
  ---
  <a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_of_the_Ozarks">
  ```{r, out.width="30%"}
  knitr::include_graphics('https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRy36.jpg')
  ```
  </a>
````

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Maybe I was not clear but my goal is that the link refers to the location of the vert sane image, thus when you click on it your browser send you to the original image with it's full size.  So the string in `href = string` should be the same than the one within `include_graphics(string)`